# Using jQuery and flexigrid, how can I pass additional values to customize the grid contents?

Tags: jquery, json, servlets, flexigrid

The usual values are passing via JSON to servlet. However, I have a requirement for a timestamp range (start and stop values) that I need to use IN ADDITION to the regular flexigrid values (page, 
qtype, query, rp, sortname, sortorder). So, I'd like to add startTime and stopTime with String values such as "09/12/2013 16:03"

I've tried using flexOptions, but must not be using it correctly since I don't get extra values passed.  Can anyone tell me how to add these two values to pass along with the others in flexigrid post to server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer.  Use this code:

```
$('#useTimeRange').change(function() {
if( this.checked ) {    //limit events to timestamp range
    //alert("Checked " + startTime + " " + endTime);
    var data = {name: 'startTime', value: $("#startTime").val()};
    var data2= {name: 'endTime',  value:$("#endTime").val()};
    $('.flex5').flexOptions({params: [ data, data2 ]}).flexReload();        
}
```

Here's the related UI and firebug:

[image: flexigrid extra params]